# Switch Visual Studio Solution source control from github and use tfs

Tags: github, tfs, visual-studio-2015

I always use TFS for source control, last week I gave github a try and use that for testing. Now I want to sync and use TFS with my solution. Everytime I open the solution it connects to github, I tried disconnecting it and connect to my tfs workspace. But won't let me. I tried right clicking the solution > source control, there's no option..

well I guess I have to download and then use the new solution to sync to tfs or use git-tfs.

Thank you in advance

Comment: When you use TFS for source control, are you using TFVC or Git?

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Git-TF](http://gittf.codeplex.com/), then run the following commands:

1. configure your GIT repository:

--

```
http://myserver:8080/tfs/mycollection $/TeamProjectA/Main
```

2. Check in the files:

--

```
git tf checkin --deep
```

————————

**Update**:

If you don't need history, you can try to unbind the source control from GitHub by going to the solution folder, delete `.git folder` (hidden folder), `.gitattributes` file and `.gitignore` file. Then commit the solution into TFS.

Comment: yeah that's what I did..it's just one solution anyway.. I was hoping for a quicker one. no other party involved..thanks anyway.

Comment: If you don't need history, you can try to unbind the source control from GitHub by going to the solution folder, delete .git folder (hidden folder),  .gitattributes file and .gitignore file. Then commit the solution into TFS.

Comment: i dont need history..as I said..I was just testing it..because the solution was in my local side not my typical dev side(VM server).. I'll try your suggestion..I was actually looking into how to disconnect it.. Thanks!!! @cece.. I don't why I can't tag you.. lol

Comment: @CyberNinja It's OK, I received the notification of your comment. Let us know whether the solution works for you.

Comment: well..it worked..can I do this vice versa with tfs -> github..jsut wondering..what if I need history..git-tf is the only way to go?

Comment: Yes, you can do this vice versa. Deleting .git folder and files will unbind git source control. If you need history, the easy way is use --deep option.

Comment: What about changing the remote url of this repository with `git remote set-url ....`?